# How to append current date into existing JSON file?

Tags: python, json, list, date, datetime

I'm using vscode
I have below format of JSON file

```
{
    "appointments": [
        {
            "date": "the date I want to add into",
            "time": "12pm"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add the date into my JSON file

**Expected:**

```
{
    "appointments": [
        {
            "date": "4-11-2021",
            "time": "12pm"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all is a simple dictionary what you have gave us.
Second of all you have a problem with brackets.

Here is your input :

```
temp = {
"appointments": [
    {
        "date": "the date I want to add into",
        "time": "12pm"
    }
]
}
```

> temp = { "appointments": [
> {
> "date": "the date I want to add into",
> "time": "12pm"
> } ] }

To get your results just run this :

```
temp['appointments'][0]['date'] = "01/01/2021"
```